# Show the record of the exact datetime value compared from mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures

Hello I'll specify the stuff I'm looking for, I have a mysql table with a datetime row, also I have this stored procedure to search for a specific date and time:

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM daterecordings
WHERE DATE(date_record) = daterec;
END
```

When I call this procedure with this (example) "2017-03-25 15:30:00" It returns me all the records in that day, not only the one at 15:30:00, I just want the specific record at that exactly hour. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `DATE` function changes the datetime format from `Y-m-d H:i:s` to just `Y-m-d`. So you're just comparing the date portion of the datetime. Remove the `DATE` function i.e. change it to

```
SELECT * FROM daterecordings
WHERE date_record = daterec;
```

Comment: This works if you really want EXACTLY that time -- you might actually prefer to search `between` a couple of times, or something like `where DATE(date_record) = daterec AND HOUR(date_record) = 15`

Comment: I think the OP made that pretty clear: "I just want the specific record at that exactly hour"

Comment: I'm working on an altert proyect, so I just calling the stored procedure each X time and comparing database time with machine time, and when they match, I receive an alert, that's why I'm looking to by exactly

Comment: Btw, it looks like it worked as Gaganshera said. Hope it doesn't bring any consequences or something.

Comment: @Becerra95 the logic I told you was correct. The code will work as you expect. If the answer worked for you, please mark it as correct/upvote. Thanks.